# Django annotation

Tags: django, aggregate

How can I count child objects in queryset?
I have model:

```
class SomeTree(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('self', on_delete=SET_NULL)
    level = IntegerField(default=0)

qs = SomeTree.objects.filter(level=0).annotate(childes_count=???)
```

I need to count direct child objects for object. Is it possible in Django ORM?

Comment: What do you mean by the child? Do you mean you want count the `SomeTree`'s objects ?

Comment: yes, I found a way using related_name='childes' option and then call `SomeTree.objects.annotate(childes=Count('childes'))`
Seams this question can be closed

Comment: Did you found my answer useful? You don't have to define any `related_name` attribute.

Comment: @Debendra I have to use related object, because I do not need count of all object, I need tocount how many childes every row has.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple, You can count the number of records just using the `count()` method.

```
qs = SomeTree.objects.filter(level=0).count()  # returns number of filtered records.
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
class SomeTree(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey('self', on_delete=SET_NULL, related_name='childes')
    level = IntegerField(default=0)

qs = SomeTree.objects.filter(level=0).annotate(childes_count=Count('childes))
```